# Why is the MOSFET not behaving as per standard device characteristic curve?

Tags: mosfet, semiconductors, powermosfet, device-characteristics

A MOSFET has 3 modes of operation:

**1.Vgs < Vth => Cutoff**

**2. Vgs > Vth and Vds < Vgs − Vth => linear region**

*The MOSFET operates like a resistor, controlled by the gate voltage relative to both the source and drain voltages*.

[image]

**3. Vgs > Vth and Vds > Vgs − Vth =>Saturation or active mode**

*The drain current is now weakly dependent upon drain voltage and controlled primarily by the
gate-source voltage*

[image]

For a certain curcuit simulation, Iam not able to figure out **why the MOSFET is behaving differently in interval 1 and 2?**
Shouldn't it be following the equation corresponding to saturation mode?
[image]

Vgs is gate-to-source bias and Vth is the threshold voltage of the device.

Edit: Below is the result when I slowed down the Vds variation

[image]

Comment: A suggestion to see more:  Try to slow down the simulation say to 10x slower. Then you'll see is it caused by the (non-linear) internal capacitance of the fet. Your equations do not take into the account such effects, they present steady states.

Comment: Are the above equation valid only for dc steady state?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a physicist who understand thoroughly the phenomenons inside mosfets. I think it only in a simple way: There's a substantial (nonlinear i.e. voltage dependent) capacitance between the G (=gate) and the rest of the mosfet. Changing voltages need some current and it's needed also in the opposite side, not only in the wire to the G.  Your equations do NOT present those currents, so they do not present the behaviour in fast enough transients. Slow down and see if the behaviour is changed. If there's no change, the effect is caused by something else, even an error in the model

Comment: Exactly. @DivyaK.S you need to get used to such equations being *models* of reality, made under *severe restrictions*; and as user287001, these restricting assumptions here are basically that things are "slow and steady". You know that transistors don't have infinite bandwidth – and these design-inherent capacitances are (one of) the reasons why.

Comment: Please show schematic and simulation model.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the MOSFET current taking time to rise in linear mode of operation?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/637624/why-is-the-mosfet-current-taking-time-to-rise-in-linear-mode-of-operation)